# Exercise 1.32 part (b) , page 24, from Graphs and Digraphs by Chartrand

Tags: graph-theory

> If $k$ is an integer such that $\operatorname{rad}G\le k\le\operatorname{diam}G$, then show that there is a vertex $w$ such that $e(w)=k$.

For a connected graph $G$ , we define the distance $d(u,v)$ between two vertices $u$ and $v$ as the minimum of the lengths of the $u-v$ paths of G.

The eccentricity $ e(v)$ of a vertex $v$ of a connected graph $G$ is the number $\max_{u \in V}(d(u,v))$. that is ,$e(v)$ is the distance between $v$ and a vertex furthest from $v$.

The **radius** $\operatorname{rad}G$ of $G$ is the minimum eccentricity among the vertices of $G$ ,

while the **diameter** $\operatorname{diam} G$ is greatest distance between any two vertices of $G$.

In other words:
$\operatorname{diam} G=\max_{u \in V}(e(v))$
and

$\operatorname{rad}G=\min_{ v \in V}(e(v))$

and
$e(v)=\max_{u \in V}(d(u,v))$.

Reference: [Original Book, *Graphs and Digraphs* By Chartrand, page 24](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/book/index.php?md5=CCE6AA121C9935E19EC651802ADF7B09)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $u$ and $v$ are adjacent vertices, then $e(v)\le e(u)+1$, right?

It's clear from the definitions that there is a vertex of eccentricity $\operatorname{rad}G$ and a vertex of eccentricity $\operatorname{diam}G$. Now suppose $\operatorname{rad}G\lt k\lt\operatorname{diam}G$, and assume for a contradiction that there is no vertex of eccentricity $k$. Let $U=\{v:e(v)\lt k\}$ and $V=\{v:e(v)\gt k\}$. Then $U,V$ are disjoint nonempty sets whose union is $V(G)$, and no vertex $u\in U$ is adjacent to any vertex $v\in V$, contradicting the assumption that $G$ is connected.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps:

Lemma 1: First prove that if $uv$ is an edge of a connected graph then $|e(u)-e(v)|\leq 1$. (Prove it.)

Then consider a path from the vertex with eccentricity $radG$ to the vertex with eccentricity $diamG$ and apply Lemma 1.